# Retrieving information from SVG object

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dot

We have an SVG graph whith nodes defined as following:

```
<!-- sac -->
<g id="node37" class="node"><title>sac</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="692.5,-952 692.5,-1004 765.5,-1004 765.5,-952 692.5,-952"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="729" y="-987.4" font-family="Times Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">sac</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="black" points="692.5,-978 765.5,-978 "/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="729" y="-961.4" font-family="Times Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">sacsip.o</text>
</g>
```

I would want to be able to add onclick element that knows what text that element that was clicked has, i.e. "saccsip.o". We have tried something like

```
 <script>
 function whichElement(event){
    var tname
    tname= event.target
    alert("You clicked on " + tname)
 }
 </script>
```

but it will only return the element, not the text itself. If the element were HTML we could have retrieved the information, but with SVG we have not succeded. Is it possible? Is there any other way?

Comment: Get [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) value of the clicked node.

Comment: What do you actually see in the alert box?

Comment: @MattEllen I got "You clicked on [object SVGTextElement]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have that code that gives DOM element i clicked on in svg:

```
    svgDOM.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log(e.target);

    });
```

so i guess something like:

```
e.target.firstChild
```

should give you the text

Comment: Adding e.target.firstChild.wholeText or e.target.firstChild.textContent does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution-ish:

```
$('#node37').on('click', 'text', function(event)
{
   console.log('You clicked on ' + $(this).text()); 
});
```

This should attack an live event listener to each text-node inside g-node with id of node37.

If you want purely JavaScript solution; I think tname.nodeValue might return the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you're doing wrong, because `ev.target` should actually work.

```
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("click",function(ev){
    var theElement = ev.target;
    //Show something nice: if we have textContent, show it,
    // otherwise just show the class.
    alert(theElement.textContent.length ? theElement.textContent : theElement.classList[0]);
});
```

Maybe it will help if you check out this [functional JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PMY4A/2/) and check with your own SVG. Additionally I could imagine that older browsers like IE might treat SVG's differently so it would be useful if you could share which browser you're using.

If indeed your problem was getting the content of the node you can use the `.textContent` property. A useful way to find these kind of things out is using `console.dir` rather than `console.log` as it will show all properties available on any element you're logging rather than the element itself. The "disadvantage" however is that you will also see a lot of browser specific quirks and properties, so checking documentation afterwards is still valuable. For example a couple of browsers support `.innerText` which however is not standardized.

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP wants the text of the element, but is actually seeing the element type in the alert.

Comment: @MattEllen: You might be right, I interpreted it as meaning he was getting the `<svg>` element logged rather than the `<text>` node. Might have indeed been mistaken.